# Jupyter and conda: error when cloning environment

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, conda, conda-forge

I have created multiple conda environments in order to test compatibility of installed packages. I use `conda create -n test02 --clone test01` to create environment test02 as a clone of test01. I activate test02, install new packages and start instance of python from which I import new packages with no problem. The problem arises when I launch jupyter notebook or qtconsole and try to import newly installed package and get import error: no module named 'xxx'. I do a `sys.executable` and see that jupyter is running python from the old environment (test01) I cloned the new one from. Why is this happening? Can I change it in config file somewhere and where might I find this file?

edit: more info

`jupyter --paths` for both environments share path entry for config and data in the same environment directory

```
(test01) PS C:\Users\Aka> jupyter --paths
config:
    C:\Users\Aka\.jupyter
    c:\users\aka\miniconda3\envs\test01\etc\jupyter
    C:\ProgramData\jupyter
data:
    C:\Users\Aka\AppData\Roaming\jupyter
    c:\users\aka\miniconda3\envs\test01\share\jupyter
    C:\ProgramData\jupyter
runtime:
    C:\Users\Aka\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime
(test01) PS C:\Users\Aka> conda activate test02
(test02) PS C:\Users\Aka> jupyter --paths
config:
    C:\Users\Aka\.jupyter
    c:\users\aka\miniconda3\envs\test01\etc\jupyter
    C:\ProgramData\jupyter
data:
    C:\Users\Aka\AppData\Roaming\jupyter
    c:\users\aka\miniconda3\envs\test01\share\jupyter
    C:\ProgramData\jupyter
runtime:
    C:\Users\Aka\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime
```

edit2: I forgot to mention that I installed Jupyter using pip.

to recreate the problem I did:

```
conda create -n env1
conda activate env1
pip install jupyter
jupyter --paths
```

> config:
>       C:\Users\Aka.jupyter
>       c:\users\aka\miniconda3\envs\env1\etc\jupyter
>       C:\ProgramData\jupyter
>   data:
>       C:\Users\Aka\AppData\Roaming\jupyter
>       c:\users\aka\miniconda3\envs\env1\share\jupyter
>       C:\ProgramData\jupyter
>   runtime:
>       C:\Users\Aka\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime

```
conda create --clone env1 -n env2
conda activate env2
jupyter --paths
```

> config:
>       C:\Users\Aka.jupyter
>       c:\users\aka\miniconda3\envs\env1\etc\jupyter
>       C:\ProgramData\jupyter
>   data:
>       C:\Users\Aka\AppData\Roaming\jupyter
>       c:\users\aka\miniconda3\envs\env1\share\jupyter
>       C:\ProgramData\jupyter
>   runtime:
>       C:\Users\Aka\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime

If I were to install jupyter with conda into a brand new environment and then clone the environment, jupyter behaves as expected. Note: I installed jupyter with pip because I am using python 3.5 because of other packages I need and installing jupyter with conda in my environments kept breaking it. I reached out to conda-forge for help but they said "sorry, we don't support python 3.5".

Comment: Have you installed ipykernel? Also, when you launch jupyter, can you select the new environment (test02) when creating a new notebook (click the drop down on new, and select test02 if it is available)?

Comment: Yes, ipykernel installed. No option or indication to select environments when creating new notebook from drop down menu in notebook app.

Comment: I think the problem is that conda environments need to be activated before a kernel is created for them. And that's something that Jupyter does not do.

Comment: @carlosCordoba, that is not the problem. The problem is that when the new environment is active and jupyter apps are started from that environment, the paths point to another environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter only needs to be install in a single location - either a Conda env or at the system-level.

### Jupyter installed in Conda env

To use other envs as kernels, one needs to install `nb_conda_kernels` in the env with Jupyter, and `ipykernel` in any env you wish to use as a kernel. Always launch `jupyter notebook` from the env with Jupyter and the others will be available automatically.

### Jupyter outside Conda

If Jupyter is installed at a system level, one must manually register the Conda envs one wishes to use as kernels:

```
conda activate my_env
conda install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name my_env_name
```

Then launch Jupyter from anywhere.

Comment: Thanks so much. This got me on the trail to what I need to accomplish. I had no idea of this possibility so probably was asking the wrong question. I am playing with the nb_conda_kernelsand got it to run my py35 kernel. I now have to figure out how to get it to run %qtconsole from within the notebook. Any idea on this? If I try it from the py35 kernel notebook, it fails silently. I then installed qtconsole into py35 env and tried from notebook and fails again with "...ImportError: No module named 'console' "